in python how to print specific value from json object that is resulting from Deepface.analyze(image)
I want to print a specific value that is 'dominant_gender'.
My code:
from deepface import DeepFace

 def detect(image):
     result = DeepFace.analyze(image,actions=['gender'])
     print(result)

detect("image.jpeg")

below is output of above code:
[{'gender': {'Woman': 0.00019092422007815912, 'Man': 99.99980926513672}, 'dominant_gender': 'Man', 'region': {'x': 298, 'y': 353, 'w': 55, 'h': 55, 'left_eye': None, 'right_eye': None}, 'face_confidence': 0.89}]

If I print(result["dominant_gender"]), I get error

list indices must be integers or slices, not str

If I print(result[1]) still I get error

It’s an array. You have to go thru each item

DeepFace's analyze function returns list of dictionary as you shared. You need to access that list's item's dominant_gender key as:
results = DeepFace.analyze(image,actions=['gender'])
for result in results:
   result["dominant_gender"]

